# jQuery: Expanding div height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 5 buttons that I would like to animate when I hover over them. What I want is to make buttons expand up not down.
Here are the codes:
http://jsbin.com/qaqoxipo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

It may look like they are expanding up, but in reality one button is pushing other buttons down. 
Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script><div id="big-buttons-container">
        <div class="big-button"></div><!--
        --><div class="big-button" style="background-color: #bb0b39"></div><!--
        --><div class="big-button"></div><!--
        --><div class="big-button" style="background-color: #bb0b39"></div><!--
        --><div class="big-button"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#big-buttons-container
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.big-button
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #D31145;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.big-button').mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    height: '+=25px',
                });
            });
            $('.big-button').mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    height: '-=25px',
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.big-button').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).animate({
                height: '+=25px',
                marginTop: '-=25'
            });
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).animate({
                height: '-=25px',
                marginTop: '+=25'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PS on Chrome at least, during the animation the bottom of the shape shakes a little - add `vertical-align: bottom` to `.big-button` to fix that.

Comment: Sir I Salute Your Awesomeness

Comment: @user3136506 Hehe thanks & see my edit on how to make the animation smoother

Answer (score 0):

You can also try hover function

```
    $('.big-button').hover(function() {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                height: '+=25px',
                marginTop: '-=25'
            });
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                height: '-=25px',
                marginTop: '+=25'
            });
    });
```

Check the link for more reference [DEMO](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Dominics code works, but now I have another problem. When I hover all the buttons, at the same time all buttons move 25px out of <div> borders.

Comment: then queue ur functions